# Vertical align a multiple line span text in display: inline-block element

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with this code, because `lorem ipsum` isn't in the middle of parent div:

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0">
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
        <a style="vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
        <a style="vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I know, I can use table-cell and a lot of other ways, but why a simple code like mine doesn't work? Is there a solution? I need IE8 support and multilines support, `position: absolute` is not a solution...

Answer (score 2):

Try giving `line-height: 100px` instead of `vertical-align`. You can use this way:

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <a style="line-height: 100px;">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
    <a style="line-height: 100px;">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image]

Or the next way is to use the `translate`, which works only in modern browsers:

```html
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0">
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: relative;">
    <a style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 50%; position: absolute;">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red; position: relative;">
    <a style="transform: translate(-50%, -50%); top: 50%; left: 50%; position: absolute;">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Preview:**

[image]

Comment: I need IE8 support, I can't use it. Line-height doesn't support multiple lines.

Comment: @Phil The first one works. Go for it. `:)`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d1be4mo0/

Comment: @Phil So it works right? What happened?

Answer (score 2):

this is the fiddle here and working with vertical-align:middle

https://jsfiddle.net/kodedsoft/txgLzycd/

code is

```
<div style="width: 500px; height: 500px; background-color: #f0f0f0">
    <div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
        <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
    <div style="display: table;vertical-align:middle; width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: red">
        <a style="display:table-cell;vertical-align: middle">lorem ipsum</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**update:
https://jsfiddle.net/kodedsoft/txgLzycd/3/
**

Comment: `I know, I can use table-cell and a lot of other ways` `:P`

Answer (score 0):

`Vertical-align` does not mean what I think you think it means.

In this instance, vertical align refers to the alignment of the element *in relation to siblings*...not within a parent (unless it's a table or table cell) (or other ancestor).

However, you don't really need it because....

Flexbox can do that:

```css
.parent {
  width: 500px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1em auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.child {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red
}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
    <a href="#">lorem ipsum</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need IE8 support, I knew this solution....